# Checking Evaluated grid value in ascx file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ascx

I'm trying to modify text in an ASCX file based on the value chosen in a grid. This syntax doesn't work.

```
 <p>
 The letter should be <%#If(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Code") == "A" Then A Else B)%>
 </p>
```

This should render as "The letter should be A" or "The letter should be B".  Can this be done dynamically? The grid is on the same ascx page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if that markup is to be inside of a grid view?

Then you still have to template that column.

So, say this:

```
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="test column">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <p>
                      <%# IIf(Eval("City") = "Edmonton", "E", Eval("City")) %>
                  </p>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

So, if the data (city column) = "Edmonton", then we show "E", else we show the value.

And that's not code - but has to be a legal single VB expression.

So, if() or iif() is a vb.net function - they are both the same - and there is no "then" or "else" when you use that function.

Comment: Oh sorry it's not in the grid view.  It's in some text that is further down in the same page.

Comment: Ok, then you can use <%=  vb expression goes here  %>  So "%# is for data bound controls only. But outside of such controls, then use %=.  So in side of that expression, you can use <%=  MyVbFunction() %>   -- that function if public in code behind can be used.